# Deserialize a JSON into a list of C# objects

Tags: c#, json, firebase, unity-game-engine, json.net

I'm developing a mobile game project that utilizes Firebase. I've managed to get login/registration, and *sending* items to the database to work just fine. However, after countless hours of banging my head against the wall, I just can't get the inventory to work. I can fetch the correct JSON data from the database, and it comes out in the following format:

```
{"5449000085757":{"itemLevel":82,"itemName":"Sword of Maximum Epicness","itemType":""},"6419800152996":{"itemLevel":45,"itemName":"Your Average Sword","itemType":""}}
```

These are all just fields for testing purposes of course. What I'm trying to do is create a list of objects, where the list is the "inventory" and the objects are the items. I've tried using Json.NET, Unity's built-in JSON utilities, all kinds of technologies, but just can't find a way. I feel kind of stupid, because obviously it can't be this difficult. No matter what example I've tried, it doesn't work.

If possible, could someone provide a quick briefing on how to create that list of objects from JSON, a simple way? I just can't figure this out on my own and it's getting really frustrating.

Comment: *No matter what example I've tried, it doesn't work.*  So where is the code which doesnt work?  It is *much* easier to help when you provide a starting point - as is, you've put all the burden on us.

Comment: It looks to me like you should be deserializing into Dictionary<string,item>  where item has the fields itemLevel, itemName and itemType.

Comment: You should rethink the json shape as it has id as type name. It could work but I would not recommend it. Following may be more appropriate { "levels": [{"id": "5449000085757","itemLevel": 82,"itemName": "Sword of Maximum Epicness","itemType": ""},{"id": "6419800152996","itemLevel": 45,"itemName":"Your Average Sword","itemType": ""}
 ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best move would be deserializing it as `Dictionary<string, object>` and Iterate through the values and casting them to your desired "Item" class.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a strongly typed class that you hydrate with your JSON you can do the following:

1. Copy the JSON payload into your clipboard.
2. In visual studio add a new class to your project. From the Edit menu select Paste Special / Paste JSON As Classes. This will create the class or classes that represent your JSON class.
3. Open tools / Manage NuGet Packages for Solution. Add NewtonSoft.JSON library to your project.
4. To hydrate your object from the JSON use something like this:

   MyObject myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonPayload);

Answer (score 1):

I would first download the [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) NuGet package. Ensure you import it into your class with `using Newtonsoft.Json`.

Then I would create an `Item` class:

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("itemLevel")]
    public long ItemLevel { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("itemName")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("itemType")]
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can simply deserialize your JSON into a `Dictionary<string, Item>` using [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm):

```
var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(json);
```

**Test**

```
var json = "{\"5449000085757\":{\"itemLevel\":82,\"itemName\":\"Sword of Maximum Epicness\",\"itemType\":\"\"},\"6419800152996\":{\"itemLevel\":45,\"itemName\":\"Your Average Sword\",\"itemType\":\"\"}}";

var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(json);

foreach (var entry in deserializedJson)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key={entry.Key}, itemLevel={entry.Value.ItemLevel}, itemName={entry.Value.ItemName}, itemType={entry.Value.ItemType}");
}
```

**Output**

```
Key=5449000085757, itemLevel=82, itemName=Sword of Maximum Epicness, itemType=
Key=6419800152996, itemLevel=45, itemName=Your Average Sword, itemType=
```